# Laravel Illuminate\Database\QueryException : could not find driver Error

Tags: php, laravel, centos, plesk

I'm using Centos 7.7 with PHP 7.2 but when I try to migrate db with laravel this error occurs. Tried many things but I can't solve this.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/saas.xxxx.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673|
```

Comment: Your centos instance is missing the php-mysql driver

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the driver
try this

```
yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php72 php-pdo_mysql
```

also it will helpy
https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-php-7-3-7-2-7-1-on-centos-7-rhel-7-centos-6-rhel-6.html

Comment: Thank you but it says Package php-mysqlnd-7.2.25-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version and same problem..